# PHP Array and Navigation Bar Drop Down List

Tags: php, html

I have a simple PHP Array called `$gatherArr` that looks like this:

```
$gatherArr = [
["catCode"=>"ac", "catName"=>"Armchair"],
["catCode"=>"sf", "catName"=>"Sofa"],
["catCode"=>"st", "catName"=>"Side Table"],
["catCode"=>"ct", "catName"=>"Coffee Table"],
["catCode"=>"dt", "catName"=>"Table"],
["catCode"=>"cs", "catName"=>"Chair / Stool"],
["catCode"=>"sb", "catName"=>"Side Board"],

];
```

I want to build a Menu bar with PHP code and get the dropdown list from the `$gatherArr`. This is my HTML code below.

```
       <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">


            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="active"><a href="index.php">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="news.php">News</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Collection <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <?php
                        include './productData.php';


                        foreach ($gatherArr as $name => $detail) {
                            echo" {$detail}<br />";
                        }
                        ?>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="ordering.php">Ordering</a></li>
                <li><a href="contactus.php">Contact</a></li>

            </ul>                                 
        </div>
```

I get lines of errors in displaying in the drop down menu bar. I have also tried change the `echo" {$detail}<br />";  To $name` but I got numbers from 0 - 6 in the menu bar

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> {$detail}

is array, You can't print or echo arrays. You can, however, print a specific element of it like:

> {$detail['catCode']}

or

> {$detail['catName']}